# Mini cart does not show on my theme

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

Here is my code to add the mini cart on my custom header .Any help?

```
<body>      
        <referenceBlock name="header.container" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
            <block  class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom_header" template="Magento_Theme::header.phtml" before="header.container"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="minicart" destination="custom_header.header" />
        
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You move block minicart to wrong destination non-exist `custom_header.header`